# Make HTTP request of the Logged in user

Tags: android, httprequest, restful-authentication

In my application I have successfully logged in to my REST server, but i need to get some more data from another activity having the user logged in. I get the following response from the server:

```
Error 15: User not Logged in
```

How do I make server requests as the Logged in User?

*p.s. when loging in i don't get any token from the server*

Comment: REST doesn't support sessions. You should authenticate every REST call.

Comment: From the guy who worked on the rest server i have a file with all links and parameters, also what it returns. on the login it is written that it will return user data, create a session and response 200. what could create a session mean?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote on the comment, but lets put it simply: if you want more information you should make another REST call to get that information. If you're using basic-auth - you should use it with ANY call you make - not only on the first call.

Comment: please put that into the answer. It solved my problem, i really have to login everytime i need some more data. that's weird...

Comment: REST is [*stateless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) (like HTTP). That's how it works.

Comment: how do i simultaneously log in and get some more data? even though i make the request just after the login, in same method, i still get response from server that i am not logged in.